# Is there any module that allows Django/Python to work with gnupg?

Tags: python, django, gnupg

I was wondering if there's any django module, or in such case any python module, that will allow me to create my own application to manage the creation, administration, etc of GnuPG keys, as well as the ability to sign and encrypt documents through this application?

If there's no such module, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GnuPGInterface](http://py-gnupg.sourceforge.net/) can [do all of that](http://sourceforge.net/docman/display_doc.php?docid=5499&group_id=29555) -- it's essentially a Python wrapper around the GnuPG program.

[PyMe](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/) might be easier to use as it is designed to wrap around GPGME (ME = Made Easy).

From [the PyME features page](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/doc/pyme/index.html):

> - Ability to sign, encrypt, decrypt, and verify data.
> - Ability to list keys, export and import keys, and manage the keyring.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Django app [django-email-extras](http://code.google.com/p/django-email-extras/) that does exactly what you're looking for. It lets users manage GPG keys via the Django admin and encrypts all mail to recipients with valid keys and includes support for multi-part templated emails with attachments.